# Where is the Textools menu?

Tags: add-on

This seems like a ridiculous question but i installed this addon called Textools by renderhjs
http://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/

I installed it(ver 2.90.1) and absolutely cannot find the tool on the interface in the UV editing workspace or the standard 3d viewport. Is this due to conflicts with the version? I definitely searched the interface for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you press <kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D viewport, a tool menu pops up in the top right corner. This menu has categories, separated by tabs running vertically on the side. Have a look and see if it added anything here (look in both edit mode and object mode):

[image]

I am basing this off the image that appears on the add-on's website - you can see all the "action" seems to happen from the same menu. The site says it has support for 2.8, but if it's not there, perhaps it isn't ready for 2.9 yet.

[image]

Comment: its really not there.

Comment: I edited the post to show where I got the idea that it might be there. If it's not, it's possible your blender version doesn't support it.

Comment: https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender

Comment: I managed to find a more update version, i believe the version on the renderhjs.net is not as updated as this one.

Comment: this version works!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Just for future reference - the GitHub one is the correct (updated) one?

Comment: The GitHub version is a version by a different developer updated for 2.8+. Renderhjs mentioned somewhere on the polycount forum they no longer have time to continue developing.

Comment: oh ic interesting. didnt know that renderhjs is not continuing development.